# Lambda and multiple statements in Python

Tags: python, lambda

Can anyone explaine that behavior of lambda functions?

```
import sys
X = lambda: sys.stdout.write('first');sys.stdout.write("second")
X()
```

Returns:
-> secondfirst

And one more problem:

```
lambda: sys.stdout.write("...");sys.exit(0)
```

Or

```
lambda: sys.exit(0);sys.stdout.write("...")
```

Doesn't execute correctly.
And one more question, why in first primer execution flow goes from right to left?

Trying with:
Python3+(3.4, 3.2) 
OS: Linux (Ubuntu), OSX

Comment: Why do you want to make a lambda like this?

Comment: I don't want to use lambda in that way, first primer was found in code of nagios plugin, and I'm was curios about why it works in that way:)

Comment: `lambda`s are *expressions* and their body must be an expression. You **cannot** put a statement inside a lambda, let alone multiple statements.

Answer (score 24):

sys.stdout.write("second") is not part of the lambda.

'second' is always printed even if you don't call X.
In other words calling X only prints 'first'.

Your code can be rewritten as;

```
import sys
X = lambda: sys.stdout.write('first')
sys.stdout.write("second")
print X()
```

If you want two statements executed by the lambda place them in a tuple;

```
lambda: (sys.stdout.write('first'),sys.stdout.write("second"))
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax for `lambda` is:

```
lambda <args>: <expression>
```

where `<expression>` must be a single expression. It cannot be a statement, or multiple statements, or multiple expressions separated by `;`.

What happens in your code is that `lambda` has higher priority over `;`, so that gets parsed as: `X = lambda: sys.stdout.write('first')` followed by `sys.stdout.write("second")`. Adding parentheses around `sys.stdout.write('first') ; sys.stdout.write("second")` would not work and produce a syntax error.

My trick to do multiple things inside a lambda is:

```
f = lambda: [None, sys.stdout.write('first'), sys.stdout.write("second")][0]
```

and the other one:

```
f = lambda: [None, sys.stdout.write("..."), sys.exit(0)][0]
```

However that kind of defeats the purpose of a lambda function, which is to do something short and really simple.

I guess that would still be OK in your specific example, but kind of looks like a hack.

Answer (score 3):

There are two statements on on line,  first is in a `lambda` that only gets `called` after the `sys.stdout.write("second")` has already run. `X()` calls the lambda.

So it does not go right to left, we just have a lambda that only gets called on the next line.  It is no different to defining a function, writing to sys.stdout and then calling that function.

Doing the equivalent with a normal function:

```
sys.stdout.write("second") 
def x():
    sys.stdout.write('first')

x()
```

For your other example you need to assign the lambda and then call it:

```
x= lambda: sys.exit(0);sys.stdout.write("...")
x()
```

Using a `;` and having multiple statements on one line is not pythonic or a very good idea generally.

Comment: 2 commands in one line confused me. I thought they was all in lambda's body.

Comment: @user4549992, that is why `;` is not really ever a good idea. Multiple statements is not pythonic and as you have found out can be confusing

Answer (score 2):

First code translates to:

```
import sys
X = lambda: sys.stdout.write('first')
sys.stdout.write("second")
X()
```

As you can see, it's now clear `second` runs before `first`.